# Create a list from a For loop in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a question about how to return the results of a For loop to a list of widgets in Flutter.

My code where the cycle is executed is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi7MW.png)

In this code example, I want to generate a list from the results of the for loop. The display should show:

- Number 1
- Number 2
- Number 3
- Number 4
- Number 5

But you can only see the "Numer 1"

Code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 32, 47);
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("List Numbers")
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return listNumbers();
  }
  
  Widget listNumbers(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      return Text('Number ${i + 1}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code within the question instead of as a linked image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using ListView.

```
Widget listNumbers(){
  List<Text> numList= [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    numList.add(Text('Number ${i + 1}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25));
  }
  return ListView(children: numList);
}
```

Comment: I thank you very much, your proposed code has worked for me. Regards!